# EXCEL Evaluate function inconsistent result

Tags: excel, vba

I have one data worksheet which is as per below format (100+ cols)

[image]

then I have another file containing some rules (multiple rules for each column in data file). I formulated vba conditions for every rule; for example, one rule was to check column A of data file should have only BP or Trip value for all rows (50K+ rows). So I translated that to below VBA

DataWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(J,X) = "BP" OR DataWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(J,X) = "Trip"

[image]

validate button code

```
        f = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 3))
        f = Replace(f, "J", 2)
        f = Replace(f, "X", 1)
        Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(f)
```

now problem is that evaluate throws type mismatch and if I use CBOOL it always return TRUE. I tried different variations too (like adding = or ? prefix) but nothing seem working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: DataWB = SourceWB both are same

Comment: What do you have in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 3)`?

Comment: I think you'd need to turn your expression (`f`) into a valid Excel formula. For example, `?Evaluate("=OR($A$2=""BP"",$A$2=""Trip"")")` should work properly.

Comment: You cannot use VBA variables like that in an `Evaluate` call.

Comment: @JustynaMK Even that is not working properly. this expression works in cell, but when i put same in evaluate it throws type mismatch; if i dont use another workbook rather another sheet then evaluate works =OR('D:\Work\[LCR16.xlsx]LCR16'!$A$2="BP",'D:\Work\[LCR16.xlsx]LCR16'!$A$2="Trip")

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does it work when LCR16 workbook is opened? After checking some sources on the internet it looks like `Evaluate` does not work with closed workbooks...

Comment: @JustynaMK Yes it works with open WB only. thanks a lot. why cant evaluate resolve workbook name with this =OR(SourceWB.Worksheets(1).cells(2,1) = "BP") while same file is used in this case. I think it only accepts absolute reference?

Comment: since i have many files, i want to give option to user to choose file and then same rules to be applied

Comment: As Rory mentioned, Evaluate cannot be used with VBA variables (like `SourceWB.Worksheets(1).cells(2,1)`). In other words, if you were to paste `=OR(SourceWB.Worksheets(1).cells(2,1) = "BP")` into your Excel window, cell A1, it would return an error as Excel doesn't recognize this syntax. However, `=OR(SheetName!$A$2="BP")` would work properly. So you need to make sure that you only parse formulas recognized by Excel (not VBA) into your Evaluate command.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate cant understand VBA Code rather excel worksheet formula can only be used, so i replaced with formula as in picture and it works perfectly now

```
For J = 2 To lRow
    For x = 2 To 26
        f = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 3))
        f = Replace(f, "WB", SourceWB.Name)
        f = Replace(f, "WS", SourceWB.Worksheets(1).Name)
        f = Replace(f, "R#", J)
        test = Evaluate(f)
        If Not test Then Call LogError(J, x)
    Next x
Next J
```

[image]